# Reallocating multidimensional array

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic-memory-allocation

Here is my code when I am reallocating multidimensional arrays. The code is not working when I use the function add_line more then once. Was trying to figure it out whole day. Can someone help?

```
void add_line(char ** wlist, char * word, int * size) // Extending wordlist or cross
{
    (*size)++;
    char ** new_wlist = (char**)realloc(wlist,(*size)*sizeof(char*));
    if(new_wlist == NULL)
        show_error("Reallocation error",1);

    wlist = new_wlist;
    wlist[(*size)-1] = (char*)malloc(ROW_SIZE*sizeof(char));
     if(strlen(word)>ROW_SIZE)
        show_error("Word too long", 1);
    strcpy(wlist[(*size)-1],word);
}
int main()
{
    int * w_size = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    int * c_size = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    *w_size = 0;
     *c_size = 0;
    char ** wordlist = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*));
    char ** cross = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char*)); 

    add_line(cross,"test1",c_size);
    add_line(cross,"test2",c_size);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does `the code is not working` mean?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not returning the modified `wlist` - here is a fixed (but untested) version of your code:

```
void add_line(char *** wlist, const char * word, int * size) // Extending wordlist or cross
              //   ^^^ note extra level of indirection here
{
    int new_size = *size + 1;
    char ** new_wlist = realloc(*wlist, new_size*sizeof(char*));
    if (new_wlist == NULL)
        show_error("Reallocation error",1);

    new_wlist[new_size-1] = malloc(ROW_SIZE);
    if (strlen(word)>ROW_SIZE)
        show_error("Word too long", 1);
    strcpy(new_wlist[new_size-1],word);
    *wlist = new_wlist;
    *size = new_size;
}

int main()
{
    int c_size = 0; // NB: no need for dynamic allocation here

    char ** cross = NULL; // NB: initial size is zero - realloc will do the right thing

    add_line(&cross, "test1", &c_size);
          // ^ pass pointer to cross here
    add_line(&cross, "test2", &c_size);
          // ^ pass pointer to cross here

    return 0;
}
```

I've also fixed a few other minor problems - the initial size of `cross` is now 0 (it was 1) and I've removed unnecessary dynamic allocation for `c_size`. I've also removed unnecessary casts, which are potentially dangerous in C, and redundant use of `sizeof(char)` (equal to 1 by definition).